# Prevent specific users from turning off network connections

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, gui, restricted-access

There is a customised Ubuntu 22.04 system with 4 users: user_a, user_b, user_c, user_d

I want to prevent 2 users (user_c, user_d) from changing Ubuntu settings. I've already locked down the terminal for these users using `rbash`.

Using `setfacl`, the GNOME Control Center has been  disabled for user_c, user_d. This was done by running this code (in a `systemd` service with sudo privileges):

```
sudo setfacl -m g:user_c:- -R /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
sudo setfacl -m g:user_d:- -R /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
```

This effectively restricts access for user_c, user_d so that they *can't even view the system settings*. user_c,user_d cannot change the Network connection settings. For example, in user_c/user_d, clicking 'Wired Settings' for any of the connections does nothing. This is fine.  See image [Ubuntu Network connection list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT537.png)

Now the question is: How can we **prevent these users (user_c, user_d)  from turning the network connections ON/OFF**? (i.e. How do we hide that the 'Turn Off' button in the connections drop-down menu).

Other users (user_a, user_b) should still be able to turn the network connections on/off and change the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnome-control-center talks to NetworkManager (via D-Bus) for configuring the network.

Even if the user cannot run the gnome-control-center application, they still can directly talk to NetworkManager via D-Bus. For example, via nmcli or nm-connection-editor or just plain dbus-send. Restricting which programs a user can run, won't work -- unless you care about only blocking users who would not know any better.

The way to restrict access to NetworkManager is via PolicyKit. See `nmcli general permissions` for the actions, and which permissions the user has. Configure PolicyKit to restrict that to certain users. How to do that exactly, is a longer story.

Most read-only operations in NetworkManager however don't get checked by PolicyKit. Every user who can talk to D-Bus, can see them. To prevent a user to even see that, configure dbus-daemon (it also has policies that can prevent users from seeing the NetworkManager API). that again would be a longer story.

Finally, D-Bus works by using a unix socket (e.g. `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`). You can also take the unix permissions away from that user to even access D-Bus at all. However, that might break a lot of things, because D-Bus is just an IPC mechanism, and you basically disable this kind of inter process communication for the user, which may be too limiting (depending on what they should do).

> How can we prevent these users (user_c, user_d) from turning the network connections ON/OFF?

`nmcli general permissions` lists `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network` PolicyKit permission. Disallow the user that.

EDIT: The permissions in the org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy PolicyKit file can be edited using the PolicyKit file found at:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy
```

For the following actions, the permissions that are set to '**yes**' by default, should be changed to '**auth_admin**' :

```
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network
```

('yes' means that the action is allowed for any users.
'auth_admin' means that the action needs to authenticated by administrative users)

Initially, I had tried only modifying the permissions for `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network` action.
However, I noticed that the non-admins could still turn the network connections on/off. So I included these other actions (listed above) as well.
This may be a bit overkill. But it works well.

Now it works as expected: For non-admin users, the option to configure the Network connection is disabled. An admin user can turn on/off the network connection after entering the password.

The different actions & permissions are documented at `freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html`